# How do I recover Windows from a lost partition?

Tags: 14.04, windows, data-recovery, partitioning

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop, which previously ran Windows Vista, I meant to run them side by side so I could boot between the two. When i got to that point in the installer it told me Vista was installed but left no option to install alongside so i clicked "something else". It took me to the partitioning window and i clicked new partition window(cause i didn't think to actually find out what it did) I went further with the install and now I'm running solely Ubuntu.

Is there any way to recover my previous Windows with files?

Or at least transfer the files to Ubuntu?

If so could you please give me detailed instructions instead of just use said program(Linux is brand new to me)

My HDD:

[image]

Outcome of terminal:
[image]

Comment: Most probably you formatted Windows partition and installed Ubuntu. Open `Disks` or `gnome-disks`, select your HDD, make a screenshot and post it here.

Comment: It looks like your Windows partition exists -> 477GB NTFS. Did you try to access it with the filemanger Nautilus? At this partition should be you files from Windwos.

Comment: You can try [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) (2nd option) to get the dual boot working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** If boot-repair fails and you want to reinstall the system to make a the dual boot work, you can follow this steps or look at the official guide here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

1. Run Ubuntu and backup your files from the NTFS partition.
2. Download the [GParted Live ISO](http://gparted.org/download.php).  Architecture dependant.
3. Burn the ISO from 1, using a burning tool or create a bootable usb drive (http://gparted.org/liveusb.php)
4. Boot the CD or USB drive
5. Delete the Entire Disk Partition.
6. Create A Windows Partition, of desired size, type NTFS, and Label it windows (be sure that it is primary partition because the windows boot-loader need this).
7. Create an ext4 partition of at least 100MB for /boot, and label it boot.
8. Subtract your RAM from the amount left.
9. Create an ext4 partition of size (Total Size - Amount in step 8), label it root.
10. Create a Swap Partition, size should be at least size of your pc memory (RAM).

After Partitioning the Disk, reinstall Windows, using the NTFS Partition created in Step 7, making sure to use the option to preserve the existing disk format.
After the Windows Install completes, reboot the computer with a Ubuntu ISO, click install, and choose something Else.  Make sure to follow your labeling scheme, i.e. mount / on the partition labeled root, mount /boot on the partition labeled boot, mount windows on the mountpoint named /windows and mount swap.  **Make sure not to format the partitions**

Save the custom layout, and continue the installer.  When asked to install GRUB install it in the partition mounted as /boot.  The installer will detect the Windows Install using os-prober, and add it to your GRUB Menu.

**Lastly, Do not use WUBI**

Comment: The OP needs to make sure OS Prober is installed and rerun the grub updater. Using this method will allow you to boot Windows from GRUB.