# After installing ubuntu 14.04 my windows 8.1 seems to be missing?

Tags: data-recovery, partitioning

I installed ubuntu 14.04 when it was still in beta, and I clicked the option run along side windows. It seems that it didnt actually do that or possibly broke the boot for it something.

I am still somewhat new to this and messing with the grubs kind of a shaky area for me. Ill attach a picture of my Gparted if that helps any. Would definately appreciate some help.

[image: http://imageshack.com/a/img838/6479/ygbv.png]

i just ran `sudo fdisk -l` and got

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x4073875b

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1   976773167   488386583+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
ccslover@ccslover-X550CA:~$
```

Comment: Is this the only hard drive? There is no NTFS partition for Windows... Can you post the output of `sudo fdisk -l` please and add it to your question.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [How do I recover Windows from a lost partition?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/463018/how-do-i-recover-windows-from-a-lost-partition)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I don't find any of my partitions after reinstalling Ubuntu. What to do?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/464765/i-dont-find-any-of-my-partitions-after-reinstalling-ubuntu-what-to-do)

Comment: There is some kind of fairness here: when upgrading from 8 to 8.1, Windows removes the grub bootloader...

Comment: I am running the testdisk now and it has found ntfs (recovery). hopefully this can be recovered. Personally I prefer Ubuntu, but MicroSoft honestly owns gaming at this point. I do appreciate everyone helping out here and will post if this fixed my issue!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it deleted your NTFS partition

I took a quick look, and this utility might let you restore the lost partition:

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/testdisk/

Hope that Helps

Comment: this is the only hard drive. I meant to post that when I edited the original post.